# Python Dictionary Fuzzy Match on keys

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary, fuzzy-search

I have the following dictionary:

```
classes = {'MATH6371': 'Statistics 1', 'COMP7330': 'Database Management', 
'MATH6471': 'Statistics 2','COMP7340': 'Creative Computation' }
```

And I am trying make a raw_input fuzzy match on the dictionary keys. For example, if I type in 'math', the output would be Statistics 1 and Statistics 2.

I have the following code, but it only matches keys exactly:

```
def print_courses (raw_input):
    search = raw_input("Type a course ID here:")
    if search in classes:
       print classes.get(search)
    else: 
       print "Sorry, that course doesn't exist, try again"

print_courses(raw_input)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Here you go:

```
>>> search = 'math'
>>> result = [classes[key] for key in classes if search in key.lower()]
['Statistics 2', 'Statistics 1']
```

Comment: def print_courses (raw_input):
    search = raw_input("Type a course ID here:")
    if search in classes:
        search = [classes[key] for key in classes if search in key.lower()]
    else: 
        print "Sorry, that course doesn't exist, try again"
        
print_courses(raw_input) #The only result I am getting is "Sorry, that course doesn't exist, try again"

Comment: @Andrew get rid of the `if statement`, check if the returned array empty.

Comment: I deleted the if statement, which then the IDE prompted me to delete the else statement. When I ran the script, nothing would output.